# Why does blending hot food in the Nutribullet blender create a "pressure seal"?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, solid-state-physics, vacuum, liquid-state

I have noticed that when blending cold foods in the Nutribullet, it is easy to unscrew the blender once the blending process is finished. When I blend something hot (i.e, boiled tomatoes, to create a tomato cream soup), I noticed it is very difficult to unscrew the blender, as if an "air-seal" had been created during the blending process. Upon opening the blender, a "frizzle noise" can be heard.

Is the difficulty all to do with the screw-on part expanding in the heat? (But that heat should also expand the plastic container, so I doubt that's all there is too it?). Is there another physical process taking place that creates some sort of vacuum seal?

Comment: Possibilities include: differential thermal expansion of parts, and a positive-pressure "seal" .   since you don't specify the delta temperature (compared with room temp) of your "cold" and "hot" ingredients, it's hard to say why there might be a difference.

Comment: Thanks @CarlWitthoft. "Cold" would be anything between refrigerated milk to room-temperature water. "Hot" would be boiled tomatoes (left to cool for 5 mins): so I suppose the hot tomatoes could be at 80 to 95 degrees Celsius.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time that you fasten the lid, the vapor pressure of the hot liquid in the head space is equal to the equilibrium vapor pressure of the liquid at the high temperature of the liquid in the container.  But, during the mixing, the liquid cools a little, and its vapor pressure decreases.  So some of the vapor in the head space condenses, and the partial pressure of the volatile species drops.  This creates a partial vacuum in the mixer chamber which is often referred to as a vacuum seal.  This is the same thing that happen in home canning of foods, and in commercial canning operations (like soups).  When you puncture the lid with a can opener, you hear the hissing of air entering the head space to equalize the pressures.

Comment: Thank you so much for the nice answer. Re-reading: "...and the partial pressure of the volatile species drops. This creates a partial vacuum in the mixer chamber" -  I still don't entirely get this part. So liquid cools, vapor in the head condenses a little bit, pressure in the head drops. How does that create a vacuum? Why can't the pressure of the vapor just drop without creating vacuum?

Comment: In science and engineering, the term "partial vacuum" just means that the pressure inside the vessel is less than the pressure outside the vessel.  In a vacuum cleaner chamber, there is a partial vacuum, not a perfect vacuum.  Please tell me that you didn't really think that a vacuum cleaner creates a perfect vacuum.

Comment: Hehe, no, my understanding of a vacuum cleaner is that it creates suction via some rotating blade inside :). So I think I finally get it: the moment I seal the Nutribullet, the pressure inside is in perfect equilibrium with the outside. But as the liquid cools via the act of blending, the inside pressure drops, and that's why the outside pressure then creates a "vacuum seal": i.e. it pressurizes the Nutribullet parts together? **Follow up question, if I may:** why does the liquid cool in the act of blending?

Comment: Suction is the same thing as "lower pressure than outside."  Air is actually forced in by the outside air once the seal is broken.  Regarding the cooling:  since the contents of the vessel are hotter than the outside air, heat is conducted out through the wall and the contents cool.  The blending enhances this heat flow by bringing hotter contents from the more interior region out into contact with the wall.  This is called convection.

Comment: Ok, that's clear now. Thank you, I've learned something ytday & today! In my book, that alone has made the two days productive / "successful" - I try and learn something new every day! :)